# flutter syncfusion calendar, event data is repeated

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I am trying to set my appointment data in one time but when I change the calendar view syn. calendar adding same data inside to the agenda view.

I want to add data once and fix to repeating datas. How can I do this?

this function adding appointment data to calendar:

```
  Future<void> handleLoadMore(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) async {

await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
final List<_Meeting> appointmentData = [];

final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var int1 = await prefs.getInt('id');
db.getConnection().then((conn) async{
  var result = await conn.query(
      'SELECT kyttr FROM  ${db_adi}.web_dis_fircalama where kytkll =? order by kyttr asc',
      [int1]);
  
    notceklist = result.toList();
    
  for(var i = 0; i < notceklist.length; i ++){
    _Meeting meetingData = _Meeting(
        '${notceklist[i]['kyttr'].toString().split(' ')[1].substring(0,5)} Saatinde dişlerinizi fırçaladınız.',
        _convertDateFromString(
            notceklist[i]['kyttr'].toString()
        ),
        _convertDateFromString(notceklist[i]['kyttr'].toString()),
        Colors.blue,
        true);
    appointmentData.add(meetingData);



  }

  appointments.addAll(appointmentData); 
  notifyListeners(CalendarDataSourceAction.add, appointmentData);
  await conn.close();
  
}
);
```

}

This is my calendar widget:

```
SfCalendar(
                initialDisplayDate: DateTime.now(),
                view: CalendarView.month,
                allowedViews: const[
                  CalendarView.day,
                  CalendarView.week,
                  CalendarView.month,
                  CalendarView.timelineWeek,
                  CalendarView.schedule,
                ],
                dataSource: _events,
                loadMoreWidgetBuilder: loadMoreWidget,
                monthViewSettings:     const MonthViewSettings(
                  appointmentDisplayCount: 3,
                    agendaViewHeight: 200 ,agendaItemHeight: 20,
                    showAgenda: true,
                    agendaStyle: AgendaStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      appointmentTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      dateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      dayTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    )),
              ),
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the same data source is being loaded for every calendar view change, which is causing the same data to be displayed. To resolve this issue, I have prepared a sample that illustrates the load more support in the calendar. In this sample, I have stored the calendar data source in a local variable, and by using the start date and end date parameters from the "**handleLoadMore**" method, I have filtered the current view appointments and added it as the calendar data source. Please find the attached sample for reference.

[https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SAMPLE~11447897636](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SAMPLE%7E11447897636)